# Design - Global Settings from Consumer Module

Tags: java, android, module, configuration

I am attempting to make a library. Had some constants in my code which were some kind of different time delays and certain String values across the code. I could extract them to a separate constant class to get something like

`Delays.LENGTH_SHORT` (seems cleaner)

They are linked to many different classes inside the library code.

Now, the problem in hand is to make it configurable, from the calling consumer (i.e., if the consumer provides the values, then use those, otherwise use the preset values). From the consumer end, I decided to use Builder pattern for creating the config and passing it in the `init` of the library module (this only happens once in the lifecycle of it).

Is there a way to keep the above syntax and yet accept the config from consumer (the settings are only configured once during `init`, for all other times, it completely behaves as constant)?

Reading from a file, appeared to be costly.

Comment: Is your library supposed as support to be implemented by other apps? Otherwise I would recommend using`SharedPreferences` for saving Strings and time durations persistently. Despite you can also use /res/values/Strings.xml to keep your default String values.

Comment: The library is supposed to be consumed by the app for certain function. In that consumption, the app can configure certain behavior of the usage during ```init``` via these settings. These settings set once, are then used in many independent classes in the library.

```SharedPreferences``` will also be like File R/W.

```strings.xml``` will not allow for over-writing in the same place if the settings are different from default (client configured), and it would need rechecking at all points of usage. Isn't it so? Am I missing out on something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For constants that can take a value from only a fixed set of values then it is always better to use Java enums instead of integers or strings or other raw data types. They are much better to understand and maintain over the period of time. Default values should ideally be read from a property file to initialize them. But as you have mentioned in your case, you want to avoid the cost of reading from a file for performance reasons. The design question is always open ended and can have multiple approaches. One approach that I recommend can be as below:

```
public interface Configuration {
    public Continent getContinent(); //For fixed set of values use enum
    public Integer getPoolSize(); //If the config can take any value then use the corresponding data type directly
    public String getDefaultLabel();
}

public enum Continent {
    ANTARTICA, AFRICA, ASIA, AUSTRALIA, EUROPE, NORTH_AMERICA, SOUTH_AMERICA;
}

public class ConfigurationBuilder {

    private DefaultConfiguration configurationInstance;

    private class DefaultConfiguration implements Configuration {

        //Ideally the below values should be read from a property file, instead of hard coding it here.
        private Integer poolSize = Integer.valueOf(50);
        private String defaultLabel = "DEFAULT";
        private Continent continent = Continent.ASIA;

        @Override
        public Continent getContinent() {
            return continent;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getPoolSize() {
            return poolSize;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDefaultLabel() {
            return defaultLabel;
        }
    }

    public ConfigurationBuilder withContinent(Continent continent) {
        this.configurationInstance.continent = continent;
        return this;
    }

    public ConfigurationBuilder withPoolSize(Integer poolSize) {
        this.configurationInstance.poolSize = poolSize;
        return this;
    }

    public ConfigurationBuilder withDefaultLabel(String defaultLabel) {
        this.configurationInstance.defaultLabel = defaultLabel;
        return this;
    }

    public Configuration build() {
        return this.configurationInstance;
    }

    public ConfigurationBuilder() {
        this.configurationInstance = new DefaultConfiguration();
    }

    public static Configuration buildDefaultConfiguration() {
        return new ConfigurationBuilder().build();
    }
}

public class Library {
    private Configuration configuration;
    public void init(Configuration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
    public void init() {
        this.configuration = ConfigurationBuilder.buildDefaultConfiguration();
    }
    private Library(Configuration config) {
        this.init(config);
    }
    private Library() {
        this.init();
    }

    /**
     * Library is not singleton here.
     * 
     */
    public static Library getInstance(Configuration configuration) {
        return new Library(configuration);
    }
    public static Library getInstance() {
        return new Library();
    }
}

public class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Configuration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .withContinent(Continent.AFRICA)
                .withPoolSize(20)
                .withDefaultLabel("Label")
                .build();
        Library lib = Library.getInstance();
        lib.init(config);
    }
}
```

Please check the Library and Client classes for usage. 
- It uses the Builder pattern. 
- It has init() and init(Configuration) methods to allow completely relying on Library defaults.
- ConfigurationBuilder supports supplying some or all configuration values to override
- Currently all three config options are overridable - continent, poolSize and defaultLabel. However if some configuration is private to Library then just remove the withXXX method for that property from the Builder.

Hope this fits your need. Good question!

Comment: Thanks for providing in your valuable inputs. They were helpful. 
Just for clarification, the constants can take "any" value (not fixed set) from consuming app client. (inside the library scope, they operate over only one value, either stock or client provided, and the timing is at init), which you also mentioned in the sample code implementation.
the code seems helpful. is there a way to use the config settings across the library code without DI?

Comment: Glad that answer can be useful. Regarding your follow up question about using the config settings across the library code withou DI, as I understand, once the library instance is initialized with a configuration instance, this configuration can be exposed via getter method like getConfiguration in the library class. The configuration instance is an immutable object here so it can be safely exposed without the risk of anyone modifying it. I didn't get the DI part, do you mean to avoid dependency of sharing Configuration interface between client and library?

Comment: I implemented the access part with dagger2 (still want to decentralize it further). The problem in hand was to not to get the classes inside the library to be interacting with the "Library" to get the the config which is relevant for those classes and not for the "Library" class.